# Is the composition of the two following functions differentiable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

I was trying to prove it via the general defintion of differentiablity.
My result was

$(h_{1}^{3}+h_{2}^{3})/(h_{1}^{2}+h_{2}^{2})^{(3/2)}$. However, i do not how to evaluate it beyond that point.

Moreover, is the function $f$ differentiable at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, because it seems like it isn't. I was thinking about proving this using partial derivatives, would this be the right way to go about it?

Comment: The definition of $\;\gamma_{a,b}\;$ doesn't seem to make much sense: it should be, I think, a function of $\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ , **not** of $\;(x,y)\;$ ...

Comment: That's what i thought!,but this was a past exam question. So, i should hope that it was not wrong!

Comment: In fact it says it maps from R to R^2 but that seems to contradict how it is defined. Since, it takes in two inputs

Comment: Well @greg : it must be wrong or else you people use notation that seems to be pretty non-standard. Not only this: it is given explicitly that the domain of $\;\gamma\;$ is $\;\Bbb R\;$ , so it is a function of **one** variable...!

Comment: I agree so i am presuming you people would agree with me when i say that, at the least, the function should take in two variables and hence be a mapping from R^2 to R^2

Comment: Nevertheless, is my method for trying to show the the function is differentiable wrong?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any sense @greg, as the question asks to show differentiability at $\;t=0\;$ ... **one** variable! And your method is a complete mistery to me as I've no idea what is that $\;h\;$ there...

Comment: h is from the general defintion which states if the function is differentiable at x_(0) there exists a linear function L such that

lim h->0 |f(x_(0)+h)-f(x_(0)-L(h)|/|h| = 0

Comment: t seems to be the users constant of the users choice.

Answer (score -1):

So the question has a typo: read    $\gamma_{a,b}(t)=(at,bt)$. If both $a,b$ are zero, this is a constant function, so the composition is also constant, hence differentiable.  Assume that not both $a,b$ are zero. Then for $t\ne 0$ we have 
$$f(\gamma_{a,b}(t))= \frac{(at)^3+(bt)^3}{(at)^2+(bt)^2} = t \frac{a^3+b^3}{a^2+b^2} \tag{1}$$ 
and for $t=0$, of course, $f(\gamma_{a,b}(t))=f(0,0)=0$. Thus, (1) holds for all $t$.
This is a *linear* function of $t$, hence differentiable.